# Handling returning users with Stripe in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm working on integrating Stripe into my Rails application. I'm having trouble finding instructions on how to handle returning users. I'm don't mean subscribers however, just user accounts who might come back and buy other items. I don't want to keep asking them for their credit card information. For example in airbnb, I put in my card once and it now remembers it. How would I do the same in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're already creating a `stripe_token` on the front end and passing it to the server, you can [create a customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later) (using the [Stripe gem](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby)) with its own token that you can persist to the database, e.g.:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  source: stripe_token,
  description: "#{user.full_name} (#{user.email})"
)
user.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
user.save!
```

I find it useful to set a good description, since this information will display in the Stripe web GUI.

You can then use this token to create new charges on demand:

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  amount: (amount * 100).to_i, # billed in cents
  currency: 'USD',
  customer: user.stripe_customer_token,
  description: "Charge",
  statement_descriptor: "Example.com Charge",
})
```

This charge also has a token that you can persist if desired:

```
user.charges.create! stripe_token: charge.id
```

Comment: This is useful, thank you. I guess I just have to find a way to separate the the user creation and charging so I'm not creating a new user whenever a purchase goes through? Cause that's what I'm experiencing at the moment. Multiple users with the same email since both methods are in the same `create` action.

Comment: @Batman I'm not sure what you mean, but yes I think the code for the charging should be separate from creating users. Creating a customer fits better with creating users. Did I answer your question above?

Comment: Yea, you did. I was following the stripe guide https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails and they have it set up so user creation and charge happen in the same action. But I guess it's more for demo purposes and not production.